# How to synchronise the time at Windows startup?

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

I can see the time synchronisation task has been already created by Microsoft, but I never was able to make it work at system start up (or right after login). I tried giving delays (30 seconds or something), tried to run it with Administrators, etc, but none of them worked.

When I manually ran the command from the console, it failed. Of course, it worked if I ran the console as administrator.

So, is there any way to make this time synchronisation task work at system start up (of course, after the Internet connection is done)? If so, how I should set the properties of the `SynchronizeTime` task?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can acomplish the samething by just using `w32tm /resync` within a command prompt/bash script/ect.  You have conflicting settings.  On one hand you have configured it to run when the user logs in on the other you have it configured to only run when the user is logged in.  It would help to know, what pratical problem you are trying to solve, in order to provide alternatives to your approach.

Comment: The computer has multiple operating systems. When I boot to Windows after using Linux, the time is wrong. So I need to correct the time when Windows starts. Running `w32tm /resync` from the command prompt (not administrator) also gave me `Access is denied` error.

Comment: Yes;  You have to run the command in an elevated command prompt.  If your user account isn't an Administrator, and a group policy is handling this behavior, you have to be an Administrator to sync the time.

Comment: My user is an administrator, but not the Administrator. That is, to use that command, I would have to click Yes on the UAC popup. Of course, no one would like to see the UAC at every boot. So, there is no way to synchronise the time without UAC at startup unless you are the Administrator?

Comment: Configure your system to allow a normal user to change the time by doing that it no longer requires you to escalate the command to an Administrator